# Join two big tables and to get most recent value

Tags: apache-spark, date, join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two Spark dataframes that have millions of rows. Assume 'id' is the common column to both dataframes. Both also have 'date' column. However, the date in the two tables may not match. If a record in the first table does not have a matching date in the second table, for the 'value' column from the second table, the most recent observation should be taken. Therefore, I cannot join on 'id' and 'date'. I have created a sample dataframes below. What is optimal way to perform this given that the data size is huge?

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3, 1,2,3], 'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-31', '2020-01-31', '2020-01-31']})

a = spark.createDataFrame(a)

b = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,1,2,1,3,1,2], 'date': ['2019-12-25', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-25', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-08',  '2020-01-21', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-31', '2020-01-31'], 'value': [0.1,0.2,0.3,1,2,10,30,0.1,0.2]})

b = spark.createDataFrame(b)

required_result = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3, 1,2,3], 'date': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-21', '2020-01-31', '2020-01-31', '2020-01-31'],
                               'value': [0.1,0.2,0.3, 1,2,0.3,10, 2,30,0.1,0.2, 30]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join on `id` and keep dates from the second dataframe which are equal to or lower than first dataframe's dates.

```py
data1_sdf.join(data2_sdf.withColumnRenamed('date', 'date_b'), 
               [data1_sdf.id == data2_sdf.id, 
                data1_sdf.date >= func.col('date_b')], 
               'left'
               ). \
    drop(data2_sdf.id). \
    withColumn('dates_diff', func.datediff('date_b', 'date')). \
    withColumn('max_dtdiff', 
               func.max('dates_diff').over(wd.partitionBy('id', 'date'))
               ). \
    filter(func.col('max_dtdiff') == func.col('dates_diff')). \
    drop('dates_diff', 'max_dtdiff'). \
    orderBy('id', 'date'). \
    show()

# +---+----------+----------+-----+
# | id|      date|    date_b|value|
# +---+----------+----------+-----+
# |  1|2020-01-01|2019-12-25|  0.1|
# |  1|2020-01-08|2020-01-08|  1.0|
# |  1|2020-01-21|2020-01-21| 10.0|
# |  1|2020-01-31|2020-01-31|  0.1|
# |  2|2020-01-01|2019-12-25|  0.2|
# |  2|2020-01-08|2020-01-08|  2.0|
# |  2|2020-01-21|2020-01-08|  2.0|
# |  2|2020-01-31|2020-01-31|  0.2|
# |  3|2020-01-01|2019-12-25|  0.3|
# |  3|2020-01-08|2019-12-25|  0.3|
# |  3|2020-01-21|2020-01-21| 30.0|
# |  3|2020-01-31|2020-01-21| 30.0|
# +---+----------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you can join just on `id`, as this key looks well distributed. You could aggregate a bit the df `b`, join both dfs, then filter and extract the value with max date.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

b = b.groupBy('id').agg(F.collect_list(F.array('date', 'value')).alias('dv'))
df = a.join(b, 'id', 'left')
df = df.select(
    a['*'],
    F.array_max(F.filter('dv', lambda x: x[0] <= F.col('date')))[1].alias('value')
)

df.show()
# +---+----------+-----+
# | id|      date|value|
# +---+----------+-----+
# |  1|2020-01-01|  0.1|
# |  1|2020-01-08|  1.0|
# |  3|2020-01-01|  0.3|
# |  3|2020-01-08|  0.3|
# |  2|2020-01-01|  0.2|
# |  2|2020-01-08|  2.0|
# |  1|2020-01-21| 10.0|
# |  1|2020-01-31|  0.1|
# |  3|2020-01-21| 30.0|
# |  3|2020-01-31| 30.0|
# |  2|2020-01-21|  2.0|
# |  2|2020-01-31|  0.2|
# +---+----------+-----+
```